# sending and receiving values on the same generator

Tags: python, generator, coroutine

I am trying to understand some of the subtle details of python generators. One of the test programs I wrote to see if I could both send and read alternatively values to/from the same generator is the following:

```
def injector():
    while True:
        try:
            print 'a'
            v = yield
            print 'b', v
            yield v
            print 'c'
        except GeneratorExit:
            print 'exit'
            break

g = injector()

print 'send none'
g.send(None)
print 'send 2'
g.send(2)
print 'receiving'
v = g.next()
print 'received', v

g.close()
```

The expected output for this program is:

```
send none
a
send 2
b 2
receiving
received 2
c
a
exit
```

The output I get is:

```
send none
a
send 2
b 2
receiving
c
a
received None
exit
```

Now, obviously, the question is why am I getting the above output ? What is it that I did not understand about how generators work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to clarify:

```
def injector():
    while True:
        try:
            print 'a'
            v = yield
            print 'b', v
            yield v
            print 'c'
        except GeneratorExit:
            print 'exit'
            break

g = injector()

print 'send none'
g.send(None)
```

Here the coroutine is started. It executes until the first yield whose result is returned from `.send()`, but then discarded.

The coroutine prints `a` and yields nothing, thus `None`. So it is ok to discard.

```
print 'send 2'
g.send(2)
```

Here you send a 2 to the coroutine, making it continue where you left it. `v = 2`.

It prints `2` and yields `v` again. You would expect that from the `g.send()` call.
So after receiving and discarding `v`, you do

```
print 'receiving'
v = g.next()
```

Here you give control to the coroutine again, which prints `c`, then `a`, then yields `None` again, which you get here.

```
print 'received', v
```

thus prints `None` for `v`.

What you probably want is

```
g = injector()

print 'send none'
g.send(None)
print 'send 2'
v = g.send(2)
print 'received', v

g.close()
```

(Note that this last block can be written more cleanly and nicely as follows:

```
from contextlib import closing
with closing(injector()) as g:
    print 'send none'
    g.send(None)
    print 'send 2'
    v = g.send(2)
    print 'received', v
```

)

Comment: Note that `next()` is exactly equivalent to `send(None)`; http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue you are having is the last call. First of all, it appears to be starting where the code left off, printing the `'c'` first. Then as the statement was not yielded, it continues in the while loop, printing `'a'`. Finally, the output is produced. The none results because nothing is yielded after the `'a'`